# tachyon0.8.2 deployed with hadoop2.6.0,but the IPC version are not matched

Tags: java, hadoop, alluxio

Now,I want to deploy the tachyon0.8.2 on my ubuntu14.04,I already has hadoop and spark:
on the master

```
bd@master$ jps
11871 Jps
3388 Master
2919 NameNode
3266 ResourceManager
3123 SecondaryNameNode
```

on the slave

```
bd@slave$ jps
4350 Jps
2778 NodeManager
2647 DataNode
2879 Worker
```

And I editor the taachyon-env.sh:

```
export TACHYON_MASTER_ADDRESS=${TACHYON_MASTER_ADDRESS:-master}
export TACHYON_UNDERFS_ADDRESS=${TACHYON_UNDERFS_ADDRESS:-hdfs://master:9000}
```

Then, I run the `bin/tachyon format`and `bin/tachyon-start.sh local`.
I cannot see the tachyonMaster in `JPS`:

```
/usr/local/bigdata/tachyon-0.8.2 [06:06:32]
bd$ bin/tachyon-start.sh local
Killed 0 processes on master
Killed 0 processes on master
Connecting to master as bd...
Killed 0 processes on master
Connection to master closed.
[sudo] password for bd:
Formatting RamFS: /mnt/ramdisk (512mb)
Starting master @ master
Starting worker @ master
/usr/local/bigdata/tachyon-0.8.2 [06:06:54]
bd$ jps
12183 TachyonWorker
3388 Master
2919 NameNode
3266 ResourceManager
3123 SecondaryNameNode
12203 Jps
```

and I see the logs in master.logs,I said that:

```
2015-12-27 18:06:50,635 ERROR MASTER_LOGGER (MetricsConfig.java:loadConfigFile) - Error loading metrics configuration file.
2015-12-27 18:06:51,735 ERROR MASTER_LOGGER (HdfsUnderFileSystem.java:<init>) - Exception thrown when trying to get FileSystem for hdfs://master:9000
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at tachyon.underfs.hdfs.HdfsUnderFileSystem.<init>(HdfsUnderFileSystem.java:74)
    at tachyon.underfs.hdfs.HdfsUnderFileSystemFactory.create(HdfsUnderFileSystemFactory.java:30)
    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystemRegistry.create(UnderFileSystemRegistry.java:116)
    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:100)
    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:83)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.connectToUFS(TachyonMaster.java:412)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.startMasters(TachyonMaster.java:280)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.start(TachyonMaster.java:261)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.main(TachyonMaster.java:64)
2015-12-27 18:06:51,742 ERROR MASTER_LOGGER (TachyonMaster.java:main) - Uncaught exception terminating Master
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All eligible Under File Systems were unable to create an instance for the given path: hdfs://master:9000
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystemRegistry.create(UnderFileSystemRegistry.java:132)
    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:100)
    at tachyon.underfs.UnderFileSystem.get(UnderFileSystem.java:83)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.connectToUFS(TachyonMaster.java:412)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.startMasters(TachyonMaster.java:280)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.start(TachyonMaster.java:261)
    at tachyon.master.TachyonMaster.main(TachyonMaster.java:64)
```

What should I do for this problem?

Comment: I think the question is at that `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)`

Answer (score 0):

This exception arises due to version mismatch of Hadoop client and server side. Check your Hadoop version, and then recompile Tachyon against that version using this command:

`mvn -Dhadoop.version=your_hadoop_version clean install`

Example: `mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 clean install`

Now configure your compiled Tachyon and it should work fine. Reference [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tachyon-users/uaYwTSsgqFo).